# Determine required Python versions from tox.ini and install if required

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, tox

tox [documentation](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) suggests that the versions of Python that you want to test against must already be installed in the environment, otherwise you'll experience errors. With that in mind, is there a generally accepted practice of checking `envlist` in `tox.ini` and using that to then install the required versions. E.g. for:

```
envlist = py27, py36
```

check if these are installed and if not, install them.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom script in order to install desired versions of python using pyenv and then use them with tox.

Some useful links about how you can install python versions with pyenv can be found here:

https://anil.io/blog/python/pyenv/using-pyenv-to-install-multiple-python-versions-tox/

https://github.com/lablup/backend.ai/wiki/Install-Python-via-pyenv

For using tox along with pyenv you can check this links as well:

http://ishcray.com/supporting-multiple-python-versions-with-tox

http://blog.pinaxproject.com/2015/12/08/how-test-against-multiple-python-versions-parallel/

Comment: Thanks @Moldovan Daniel. All very useful. My problem is that my tests may get run on any one of a number of servers and the serversmay or may not have all the versions of Python that I want to test on. For this reason, when the `tox` command is run, I'd like my custom script to check the versions in `envlist`. Any that are not there should be installed, once done, the command to execute my tests should be run. Are there any pitfalls I shold be aware of in trying this?

Comment: As long you install python versions with pyenv I don't see any major pitfalls except the fact that the python versions need to be specified in a different format in tox.ini than pyenv (py27, py36 vs 2.7.0, 3.6.8). This can be fixed with a mapping/adaptation logic in the script or you can just keep duplicate list of python versions for both tox & pyenv.